# Street traffic flow (from Azure Map GeoJSON) to OpenStreetMap street network (graph)

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, traffic, osmnx, azure-maps

The Ultimate Goal: I am trying to find the shortest and least traffic path between two points for a given pair of latitudes and longitudes on the map. This is rather standard in most of the maps, but not publically available at least the traffic data, to the best of my knowledge.

Achieved So Far:
I have successfully retrieved street networks from OpenStreetMap using [osmnx](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx) Python library for routing optimization using the integrated [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) library. It works fine and I have a up and running prototype resembling standard maps out there for route navigation based on e.g Dijkstra or A star algorithm.

I need to retrieve the traffic flow data as well. Such data is not available in OpenStreetMap (if it is please let me know). I use an [Azure Map API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/render/getmaptile) that returns a GeoJSON containing traffic flow embedded in map tiles (PBF format) querying for a particular pair of latitude, longitude.

A typical GeoJSON from this API at zoom level of 15 for a random location in Berlin `52.519819, 13.297018` (about [zoom levels and tile grids](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/zoom-levels-and-tile-grid?tabs=typescript)) is:

```
    {'extent': 4096,
 'version': 2,
 'features': [{'geometry': {'type': 'MultiLineString',
    'coordinates': [[[4470, 158],
      [4480, 156],
      [4250, 150],
      [4072, 128],
      [3444, 68],
      [2800, 2],
      [2578, -18],
      [2032, -74],
      [1682, -118],
      [604, -230],
      [-410, -338]],
     [[445, -410],
      [582, -394],
      [1252, -342],
      [1700, -302],
      [2048, -264],
      [3090, -156],
      [3298, -140],
      [3460, -132],
      [3796, -108],
      [4330, -84],
      [4506, -90]],
     [[4506, 1771],
      [4440, 1558],
      [4410, 1412],
      [4400, 1322],
      [4390, 1154],
      [4390, 958],
      [4406, 722],
      [4424, 554],
      [4450, 358],
      [4500, 24],
      [4506, -10]],
     [[4506, 153], [4480, 156]]]},
   'properties': {'road_type': 'Secondary road',
    'traffic_level': 1.0,
    'traffic_road_coverage': 'full'},
   'id': 0,
   'type': 2},
  {'geometry': {'type': 'LineString',
    'coordinates': [[1682, -118], [1709, -410]]},
   'properties': {'road_type': 'Major local road',
    'traffic_level': 0.8029999732971191,
    'traffic_road_coverage': 'full'},
   'id': 0,
   'type': 2},
  {'geometry': {'type': 'LineString',
    'coordinates': [[2062, -410], [2048, -264], [2032, -74]]},
   'properties': {'road_type': 'Major local road',
    'traffic_level': 1.0,
    'traffic_road_coverage': 'full'},
   'id': 0,
   'type': 2},
  {'geometry': {'type': 'LineString',
    'coordinates': [[4506, 3362],
     [4306, 3406],
     [4168, 3448],
     [3962, 3536],
     [3852, 3600],
     [3760, 3658],
     [3690, 3708],
     [3620, 3754],
     [3518, 3860],
     [3444, 3998],
     [3340, 4232],
     [3260, 4442],
     [3237, 4506]]},
   'properties': {'road_type': 'Minor local road',
    'traffic_level': 1.0,
    'traffic_road_coverage': 'full'},
   'id': 0,
   'type': 2}]}
```

I have also managed to learn more about this tile and the information that is being stored within using [mercantile](https://github.com/mapbox/mercantile) Python package. For example I can easily get the tile's bounds, quadkey and even visualize the tile for verification, for example this tile is like:

[image]

Intuitively I can see that GeoJSON contains traffic flow for major roads, local roads etc.

The Challenge:
However, I am struggling to learn best practices to extract/flatten this GeoJSON in order to merge it to the OpenStreetMap graph or somehow parse in a way that I can pass it to OpenStreetMap street graph for the Ultimate Goal. Or I may need to rethink the way I am trying to solve the problem?! At the moment, I wouldn't even know whether the way I query from the Azure API is correct. I mean I need to send a location query for each tile to get all the tile GeoJSON (kind of does not make sense). Imagine how I should then retrieve such data for a city or country. I am confident a better should be there, the way osmnx returns a whole city street graph in a one liner:

```
osmnx.graph_from_place("Berlin, Germany", which_result=2, network_type='drive')
```

One should be logically able to retrieve the whole city traffic data on the same graph. At least I have not figured it out just yet! I am looking for hints, suggestions to move in the right direction. As you might have already guessed this is my first exposure into geodata, maps at this scale.